# PaintCode expression for dynamic stroke width based on frame

Tags: expression, paintcode

I've got a bezier with a stroke which is contained within a frame. My bezier resizes dynamically along with the frame very nicely, but the stroke width is static which makes it look bad at small sizes. (Notice how the stroke isn't proportional on the small star below.)

[image]

My first thought was to make the stroke width (normally 5) an expression that was based something like `5.0*(frame.width/standardwidth)` but I'm not allowed to reference the frame variable.

How can I make an expression to calculate a stroke width based on the frame width? Or somehow make the stroke width dynamically sized like the rest of the elements within the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this works out of the box. That is:

*"...somehow make the stroke width dynamically sized like the rest of the elements within the frame"*

Versions:

- PaintCode 3.4 (34000)
- Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000)
- Swift 4.1.2

> PaintCode Setup

[image: PaintCode Setup]

> Custom View

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class StarView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        StyleKit.drawStarIcon(frame: rect)
    }
}
```

> Final Result

[image: Final Result]

> GitHub

https://github.com/backslash-f/paintcode-tests

Comment: It doesn't look like you have your star inside a frame. When I put a frame around the star, then I don't get that Resizing option that you have (it's greyed out).

Comment: ... and the stroke on my star stays at a static size which means it is thicker than it should be proportionally.

Comment: Oh, that’s true. I don’t use Frames for simple resizing operations anymore. I remember they were absolutely necessary in previous PaintCode versions, but can now be dismissed in most cases. Do you really need that Frame?

Comment: Yeah, I just came back to essentially post what you just did. What I'm trying to do required a frame in PaintCode 1 and 2, but this new PaintCode 3 automatic resizing thing seems to inherently do what I want without having to mess with frames. Thanks!